# Backup and restore only C:\ Drive from boot?

Tags: windows, backup, restore

Is it possible in Windows 8/8.1 systems to back up the entire C:\ Drive and restore it from boot without erasing your other data on hard drive placed in e.g. D: or E: drives? So that you only restore complete C:\ leaving other partitions untouched and safe.

Comment: There are dozens of programs that will image your HDD and allow you to restore specific partitions from that image.

Comment: @Ramhound: Would windows 8.1 system backup restore do that?

Comment: It will to a certain point, but it won't do what you describe fully, hence the reason third-party software should be used instead.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am asking for that specific third-party software (if possible freeware). Surely not all of hundreds would do that.

Comment: macrium reflect free.  Get it from softpedia so a direct download no junkware download manager http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Macrium-Reflect-Free-Edition.shtml  And make a rescue CD.. Whatever imaging program you use, look for a rescue cd/usb.. And label your drives/partitions to make sure you don't restore to the wrong one.  And you might want to physically remove any hard disks you don't want to write to - just to make sure

Comment: @user125221 and I agree, ramhound is probably wrong about there being "hundreds"  and there are no doubt probably < 10  that most people use anyway, that are generally reasonably good, though he is unwilling to name a single one for you in any of his comments to your requests for info. but anyhow , I linked you to Macrium Reflect Free. You can look up about imaging programs, that's what you are after

Comment: @user125221: requesting software recommendations is off-topic.  Almost any backup software will do what you want.  Be careful when you Google it not to trip over all of the recommendations you find.  If you Google "reviews", you will find comparisons of the common programs.

Comment: @barlop: Be nice.  Your gratuitous swipes at Ramhound have been going on for a long time.  Please put it to bed.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can just restore the `C:` drive and leave all of the other drives untouched. When you boot into the install CD, or however you plan on doing this, just don't touch `D:`, `E:`, etc. I've done this a few times on my personal computer, reformatting `C:` and leaving the other drives untouched.

Comment: I don't get it. How do you create the backup of entire C and restore it?

Comment: @user125221 - There are hundreds of programs that can do this.  Pick the one you like the best.